# How to use python to scrape data from a page with multiple dynamic selection fields?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping, and am trying to use python to scrape specific contents from this page: [TRAC - People and Staffing](http://tracfed.syr.edu/index/index.php?layer=fedstaf&ds=pros)

The data that I need to get is the counts (don't even need the names) of attorneys for each district in the list, both historical, and recent.

I have googled and imported beautiful soup and dryscape. I've read through several tutorials, but I don't know javascript, so I'm having a hard time figuring out which package is best, and how to alter the sample codes I have found.

edit: I don't have a subscription to this database, but when I look at the source code, I can see all the data that I need:

[image: Screenshot]

This shows a list of names when one district and one time period are selected; essentially, what I need is a way to iterate this automatically and store the output, sorted by district.

Comment: Did you try googling "python web scraping"? You should do that and then ask a specific question regarding what exactly gives you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to know JavaScript to do web scraping.

Open your developer tools, *Network* tab and try changing districts in the form. You'll see that your browser does http requests to some addresses: one of those contains the data you need:

[image: Developer Tools]

Browser performs a GET resuest to an address like http://tracfed.syr.edu/express/fedstaf/initials/hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_Arizona.html and gets a response that looks like this one:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var group= new Array() ;
   group[0] = new Array("Aguilar, Arturo","14006");
   group[1] = new Array("Albert, Jerry R.","00113");
   group[2] = new Array("Alexander, Bret S.","13950");
   group[3] = new Array("Anderson, Beverly K.","10220");
   group[4] = new Array("Arellano, Raquel","00114");
   group[5] = new Array("Bachus, Alison S.","13936");
   group[6] = new Array("Barry, Patrick T.","13937");
   group[7] = new Array("Battista, Frederick A.","00119");
   group[8] = new Array("Bibles, Camilla","00121");
   group[9] = new Array("Bostwick, Reese V.","00123");
   group[10] = new Array("Boyle, John Z.","10223");
   group[11] = new Array("Brown, Christopher A.","13982");
   group[12] = new Array("Bullis, Paul","14005");
   group[13] = new Array("Cabanillas, Cristina M.","00126");
   group[14] = new Array("Cassell, Matthew Colson","14017");
   group[15] = new Array("Cerow, Darcy A.","00127");
   group[16] = new Array("Christiansen, Callie","14010");
   group[17] = new Array("Clausen, Monte C.","00132");
   group[18] = new Array("Clemens, Shelley K. G.","13931");
   group[19] = new Array("Cocio, Fredrick A.","13945");
   group[20] = new Array("Corbin, Carmen","13996");
   group[21] = new Array("Coughlin, Robert E.","14022");
   group[22] = new Array("Davenport, Gordon","13985");
   group[23] = new Array("DeJong, Sarah Elizabeth","14014");
   group[24] = new Array("Decosta, Sabrina","13952");
   group[25] = new Array("Dejoe, Ryan","14001");
   group[26] = new Array("Demarais, Ann L.","13962");
   group[27] = new Array("Dokken, Roger W.","00135");
   group[28] = new Array("Duryee, Carin","00138");
   group[29] = new Array("Eltringham, Matthew G.","14019");
   group[30] = new Array("Evans, John Reynolds","05657");
   group[31] = new Array("Feldmeier, Mary Sue","00142");
   group[32] = new Array("Fellrath, Robert A.","13981");
   group[33] = new Array("Ferg, Bruce M.","10234");
   group[34] = new Array("Ferraro, D. Thomas","10236");
   group[35] = new Array("Figueroa, Jesse J.","00143");
   group[36] = new Array("Fisher, Joshua Ivan","14012");
   group[37] = new Array("Flannigan, David P","10237");
   group[38] = new Array("Fugitive","00141");
   group[39] = new Array("Galati, Frank T.","13927");
   group[40] = new Array("Galbraith, Charles","13998");
   group[41] = new Array("Granoff, Jonathan B.","10241");
   group[42] = new Array("Granoff, Liza M.","13941");
   group[43] = new Array("Green, Jennifer E.","13954");
   group[44] = new Array("Greer, Dyanne C.","10242");
   group[45] = new Array("Hanley, Joseph","13997");
   group[46] = new Array("Hansen, Sandra M.","00153");
   group[47] = new Array("Healey, Kyle","13994");
   group[48] = new Array("Hernandez, Rachel","00155");
   group[49] = new Array("Hodahkwen, Marnie","14002");
   group[50] = new Array("Hollon, Leta","13971");
   group[51] = new Array("Hopkins, Kimberly E.","13989");
   group[52] = new Array("Howe, Randall","13969");
   group[53] = new Array("Hurley, Emory T.","10248");
   group[54] = new Array("Hyder, Charles F.","00159");
   group[55] = new Array("Jennis, Lisa","00161");
   group[56] = new Array("Kasprzyk, Brian","13976");
   group[57] = new Array("Kelly, Kristen","14003");
   group[58] = new Array("Kern, David A.","00166");
   group[59] = new Array("Kim, Wendy","13991");
   group[60] = new Array("Kimmins, Lynnette","00167");
   group[61] = new Array("Kirby, Vincent Q.","00168");
   group[62] = new Array("Kleindienst, Wallace H.","00170");
   group[63] = new Array("Kleiner, Albert L.","10255");
   group[64] = new Array("Knapp, James Richard","13940");
   group[65] = new Array("Koehler, Joseph E.","00172");
   group[66] = new Array("Kokanovich, Mark Samuel","14021");
   group[67] = new Array("Lacey, James T.","00174");
   group[68] = new Array("Landis, Brent H.","13968");
   group[69] = new Array("Langhofer, Kory","13992");
   group[70] = new Array("Lanham, Krissa","14009");
   group[71] = new Array("Lanza, Dominc","13984");
   group[72] = new Array("Laramore, Stephen W.","00175");
   group[73] = new Array("Larson, Brian","00176");
   group[74] = new Array("Lee, Lawrence C.","13987");
   group[75] = new Array("Lee, Michael A.","10258");
   group[76] = new Array("Lefkowitz, Claire K.","00177");
   group[77] = new Array("Lemke, Kathy","13951");
   group[78] = new Array("Levinson, Jennifer F.","13964");
   group[79] = new Array("Lewis, Christopher J.","13963");
   group[80] = new Array("Lodge, Joseph J.","00180");
   group[81] = new Array("Logalbo, Michael D.","13932");
   group[82] = new Array("Logan, Steven P.","00181");
   group[83] = new Array("Lopez, John R., IV","10261");
   group[84] = new Array("Lucca, Jonell L.","13965");
   group[85] = new Array("Maingot, Anthony Edward","13939");
   group[86] = new Array("Markovick, Erick","00183");
   group[87] = new Array("Marlowe, Joelyn D.","00184");
   group[88] = new Array("McCallum, Erica","13973");
   group[89] = new Array("McCormick, Glenn B.","10267");
   group[90] = new Array("McDonald, Karen S.","00190");
   group[91] = new Array("McGhee, James","14007");
   group[92] = new Array("McGhee, Melanie A.","14018");
   group[93] = new Array("McLaughlin, Jane E.","13960");
   group[94] = new Array("McMurray, Molly","14008");
   group[95] = new Array("Meister, Melissa","14004");
   group[96] = new Array("Melissa, Karlen","13978");
   group[97] = new Array("Mellor, Joshua C.","13988");
   group[98] = new Array("Miskell, Robert L.","00193");
   group[99] = new Array("Morrissey, Michael T.","00194");
   group[100] = new Array("Morse, James B.","13953");
   group[101] = new Array("Mosher, Anne E.","00195");
   group[102] = new Array("Nelson, Heather H.","13957");
   group[103] = new Array("Novitsky, Sharon K.","00198");
   group[104] = new Array("Parecki, Josh P.","13958");
   group[105] = new Array("Passos, Raynette","00201");
   group[106] = new Array("Peery, Amy Elizabeth","14020");
   group[107] = new Array("Perkel, Walter P","13977");
   group[108] = new Array("Petermann, David P.","10272");
   group[109] = new Array("Phillips, Sheila","13979");
   group[110] = new Array("Picton, Cory","13972");
   group[111] = new Array("Pimsner, David","00203");
   group[112] = new Array("Pop, Anca","13999");
   group[113] = new Array("Rapp, Kevin M.","00206");
   group[114] = new Array("Rassas, Theresa","13970");
   group[115] = new Array("Reid-Moore, Christina","13990");
   group[116] = new Array("Restaino, Gary M.","10274");
   group[117] = new Array("Rocker, Wilbert L., Jr.","13959");
   group[118] = new Array("Roetzel, Danny N.","10276");
   group[119] = new Array("Rolley, Karen","14000");
   group[120] = new Array("Rood, Paul V.","00209");
   group[121] = new Array("Russell, Craig Howard","14016");
   group[122] = new Array("Sampson, Dimitra H.","13967");
   group[123] = new Array("Sardelli, Brian G.","14015");
   group[124] = new Array("Savel, Nicole P.","10277");
   group[125] = new Array("Scheel, Ann B.","00212");
   group[126] = new Array("Schmit, Gerard Micah","13956");
   group[127] = new Array("Schneider, Patrick J.","00213");
   group[128] = new Array("Sexton, Peter S.","00214");
   group[129] = new Array("Sharda, Munish","10278");
   group[130] = new Array("Silver, James Anthony","13949");
   group[131] = new Array("Simon, Thomas C.","00216");
   group[132] = new Array("Spaven, Michelle","13995");
   group[133] = new Array("Strange, Elizabeth A.","13961");
   group[134] = new Array("Sukenic, Howard D.","10283");
   group[135] = new Array("Timm, Craig M.","13983");
   group[136] = new Array("Tsethlikai, Serra","00220");
   group[137] = new Array("Uhl, Louis","13974");
   group[138] = new Array("Van Buskirk, Tracy","13986");
   group[139] = new Array("Vercauteren, Keith E.","10285");
   group[140] = new Array("Walsh, Janet M.","10286");
   group[141] = new Array("Wang, Rui","13993");
   group[142] = new Array("Wiles, Jennifer Marie","14011");
   group[143] = new Array("Woo, Cassie","13975");
   group[144] = new Array("Woo, Raymond K.","13943");
   group[145] = new Array("Woolridge, Angela W.","13942");
   group[146] = new Array("Zipps, David R.","13980");
parent.frames['form'].changeAUSAMenu(group); 
delete group ; 
//-->
</SCRIPT>
<HTML><BODY BGCOLOR="#F5F6C8"></BODY></HTML>
```

Now that sure is a weird way developers chose to respond to AJAX requests (usually client-server interaction on web pages is done with JSON/XML), but nevertheless we can parse that data with not so complicated regular expressions (I'll leave it to you to figure out how to write one that would extract attorney names from the response text).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Ok, it looks like I was looking at the wrong sub-page (judges, rather than prosecutors).  The correct page is http://tracfed.syr.edu/express/fedstaf/initials/crimlist_pros.html

If you look at the page source, lines 76, 82, and 85 you see that when you update the `distric2` select-box or the `period` radio-buttons it calls a javascript function named `updateAUSAMenu()` which changes the content of the prosecutor select-box.

That function is defined in lines 189 - 206; with some tidying and some comments added, it looks like

```
function updateAUSAMenu() {
    // get name of currently-selected district
    var DistName = document.forms[0].distric2.options[document.forms[0].distric2.selectedIndex].value;
    // clean up district name - remove commas, periods, and spaces
    DistName = replace(DistName, ',', '');
    DistName = replace(DistName, '.', '');
    DistName = replace(DistName, ' ', '');

    // decide which period is selected (recent or historical)
    var period = document.forms[0].period[0].checked;
    var insert;
    if (period==true) {
        insert= "";       // recent
    } else {
        insert="hist_";   // historical
    }

    // debug message
    // alert("./hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_" + insert + DistName + ".html");

    // build url
    var newurl = "./hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_" + insert + DistName + ".html" ;
    // load update script in a hidden frame
    // (loading the script runs it, and it then updates the prosecutor select-box)
    parent.frames['hidden'].location = newurl;
}
```

Looking at this, you can see that the generated urls are of the form

```
./hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_{district}.html        # recent
./hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_hist_{district}.html   # historical
```

You can grab the list of districts directly from `http://tracfed.syr.edu/js/district_selector.js` like so:

```
# assuming Python 3 with requests module:
import re
import requests

url       = "http://tracfed.syr.edu/js/district_selector.js"
js        = requests.get(url).content.decode()
districts = re.findall(r'<option value=\\"(.*?)\\">', js)

# looking at the values in `districts`, there are no periods or commas
#   or internal spaces; all we need to do is strip trailing spaces
districts = [d.strip() for d in districts]
```

then we can get per-district prosecutors like

```
from time import sleep

base     = "http://tracfed.syr.edu/express/fedstaf/initials"
rec_url  = base + "/hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_{district}.html"
hist_url = base + "/hidden_ausa/menu_ausa_hist_{district}.html"

# set up data structure
data = {
    district: {"recent":[], "historical":[]}
    for district in districts
}

# go get data!
for district in districts:
    # get recent data
    url  = rec_url.format(district=district)
    js   = requests.get(url).content.decode()
    pros = re.findall(r'Array\("(.*?)"', js)
    data[district]["recent"] = pros
    num_rec = len(pros)
    sleep(5)

    # get historical data
    url  = hist_url.format(district=district)
    js   = requests.get(url).content.decode()
    pros = re.findall(r'Array\("(.*?)"', js)
    data[district]["historical"] = pros
    num_hist = len(pros)
    sleep(5)

    # show progress
    print("{}: {} hist, {} rec".format(district, num_hist, num_rec), flush=True)
```

which gives

```
Ala_M: 40 hist, 16 rec
Ala_N: 77 hist, 32 rec
Ala_S: 32 hist, 15 rec
Alaska: 34 hist, 21 rec
# etc...
```

then you will need to figure out how to store `data` for further use.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @Hugh. In case I was unclear in my original post, I don't have a subscription to this database, but when I look at the source code, I can see all the data that I need: http://imgur.com/FAnr4BA (this shows a list of names when one district and one time period are selected; essentially, what I need is a way to iterate this automatically and store the output, sorted by district.)

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help on this; it is much appreciated!